# author name in biblatex's reading style

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the `reading` style of `biblatex` I've already deleted the entry key with the option `entrykey=false`. Now I want (respectively have to) to have the Authors name on this position (right-justified) and the titles left justified in the same line. Like this (without the underscores)

> BookXY_________________________________________________________AuthorofBookXY

Then the horizontal line and then the rest of the information.

I hope that I've provided you with the necessary information.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is sort of clear already, but you can make our lives easier by provding an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). An MWE makes sure we are all talking about the same thing, it allows us to test our solutions with your actual set-up and it helps us to get started more quickly since we don't have to replicate what you have already.

Comment: What happens if the title is too long to fit into one line?

Comment: Well I think it is such a general question about the bibtex respektive the reading.bbx file itself, and it should work on any document anyway. But next time I will provide a MWE.

Comment: Well in the best case the authors Name is in an own collumn, but for now I don't have to worry about that. I also think that this can't be solved that easily - But I'm new to LaTeX, so i don't know. --- Oh I see you already have an answer fot that thanks.

Comment: I think providing an MWE is a curtsey in this case, it shows that you value the time of those trying to answer your question since they won't have to rebuild what you already have. As I said an MWE is not required in this case, but it often is and it is a good thing to make a habit of providing one. Some cases might not be as clear cut and erring on the side of including an MWE is never a bad thing.

Comment: The second bit of code in my answer results in something akin to a tabular setup with two columns.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Haven't thought about that, it's my first question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=reading, entrykey=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{entryhead:full}{%
  \printfield{labeltitle}%
  \hfill
  \printnames[labelname][-1]{labelname}}

\begin{document}
\cite{cicero}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

works but has understandable problems with titles that are too long. Name lists are shortened to the first author only to save space.

```
\renewbibmacro*{entryhead:full}{%
  \parbox[b]{.6\textwidth}{\raggedright\printfield{labeltitle}}%
  \parbox[b]{.4\textwidth}{\raggedleft\printnames[labelname]{labelname}}}
```

gives OK-ish results for longer titles and prints all names. You can vary the size of the parboxes.

Comment: I've tested the second part of your answer. Is it possible, that the authors name appears on the top? Now it's on the hight of the last line of the title.

Comment: @DanilS Ah, I preferred that look. I feel that the horizontal rule should be the baseline. Change `\parbox[b]` ("bottom") to `\parbox[t]` ("top").

Comment: Oh, I see. I should also have to be able to figure that out myself. Thank you a lot and good night.